# restrict users to red5 url but still serve via webpage

Tags: red5

How can you restrict who can use the red5 5080 page for connecting and viewing a stream but allow any users to view it when served from a web page?

I'm having trouble making sense of it because I am going to have individuals connect to stream their camera broadcast remotely to my server where red5 is installed via the 5080 pages and want to be able to limit access to just their IP and mine on there but I want all viewers to have access via embedded player broadcasting the stream on my web page. Of course the url embedded in player equals the 5080 page file directory so don't see how this is possible, plus there is nothing stopping anyone who knows about red5 to just go to mysite.com:5080 and connect or view.

Comment: Well it seems to me it is a matter of creating your own apps and hiding usual directory roots. That is what I suspect.